# onAppOpenAttribution not called for deep links with AppsFlyer

Tags: ios, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I have integrated the AppsFlyer SDK into my project. I have managed to get deep links working. Any links I make in OneLink will open the app as desired. However I have no way to access the link parameters. I have implemented all the following delegate methods like so:

```
func onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    print("Test 1")
}

func onAppOpenAttributionFailure(_ error: Error!) {
    print("Test 2")
}

func onConversionDataReceived(_ installData: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    print("Test 3")
}

func onConversionDataRequestFailure(_ error: Error!) {
    print("Test 4")
}
```

Not one of them is called when my app is open from a deep link. What am I missing here? In my URL that is configured in the control panel I have `mycompany://` configured as the `Mobile deeplink URL`. Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: what iOS SDK version do you use? Did you register to `delegate`? If you open app not through deep-link,  `onConversionDataReceived`  is called? Also please post AppsFlyer initialization

Comment: @MaximShoustin `onConversionDataReceived` do you know why not getting called even I have sets delegate = self

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't yet, please add the following method to your delegate:

```
// Reports app open from a Universal Link for iOS 9
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {    
    [[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker] continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
    return YES;
}
```

This will pass the link data to the AppsFlyer Tracker and `onAppOpenAttribution` should be called as a result.

Comment: I have added this, yet its not get called, any idea ?

Comment: Are you setting the `[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker].delegate = self` ?

Comment: Why am I getting this error "Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate!'" @poblobart

Answer (score 3):

I just had to:

1. Restart my Xcode
2. [Redownload provisioning profiles](https://www.evernote.com/l/ArHEwRQrZdZB9YGzmlznvy5ytxw4M6CtcWk)

3) Make sure you're on a real device with the Xcode project backgrounded when you click on the link.

4. Make sure `AppsFlyerTracker.shared().delegate = self` is in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the AppDelegate file.

Comment: When I add the 4th point, I get this error **"Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate!'"**

Comment: Hello Chetan,  please add the `AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate` to the class like so:  `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,` **AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate** `{`

Answer (score 1):

According to the AppsFlyer document: [initializing the SDK](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032066-iOS-SDK-integration-for-developers#integration-33-initializing-the-sdk), you need to check the following conditions:

- Invoke `AppsFlyerTracker.shared.trackAppLaunch()` when `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` posted or in the function `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)`.
- Set `AppsFlyerTracker.shared.isStopTracking = false`
- Pass `userActivity` to `AppsFlyerManager.shared.continue(_)` in `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` for universal link (http:// or https://).
- Pass URL and options to `AppsFlyerManager.shared.handleOpen(_:options:)` in `application(_:open:options:)` for deep link (custom scheme).
- Set tracker delegate to `AppsFlyerTracker.shared.delegate`.

After calling `AppsFlyerTracker.shared.trackAppLaunch()`, the callback function `onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData:)` of the delegate will pass the link information as well.